# Is there a way to save EnvDTE Project global variables to the vcxproj.user file rather than the .vcxproj file?

Tags: visual-studio-extensions, vsix, envdte

As the title states, I'm trying to save data to the user file (**projectname.vcxproj.user**) rather than the project file (**projectname.vcxproj**)

Reading the variable (or initialising it) is done like this:

```
var globals = project.Globals;

string readValue = "";

if (!globals.VariableExists["variablename"])
{
    globals.VariablePersists["variablename"] = true;
}
else
{
    readValue = (string)globals["variablename"];
}
```

and writing the data is done with this line

```
var globals = m_project.Globals;
globals["variablename"] = "write this value";
```

However, the data gets written into the **.vcxproj** file as

```
  <ProjectExtensions>
    <VisualStudio>
      <UserProperties variablename="write this value" />
    </VisualStudio>
  </ProjectExtensions>
```

rather than into the **.vcxproj.user** file. Is it possible to write to **.vcxproj.user** instead?

Comment: Hi friend, do you have update? Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is few information about `.vcxproj.user` file, you may have read this doc: [.user files and why they are problematic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2012/669zx6zc(v=vs.110)?redirectedfrom=MSDN#user-files-and-why-they-are-problematic) or this doc: [.vcxproj.user files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/porting/build-system-changes?view=msvc-160#vcxprojuser-files).

Normally, the properties are set/stored in `.xxproj` file by default these days. Due to some reasons, the `.user` file is used for specific properties, or under specific circumstance.

I believe the global variables are written to the `.vcxproj` file by default, and it is not possible to write the global variables to the `.vcxproj.user` file.

Comment: Thanks. I ended up writing to my own, local xml file.